# how to send downloaded text using volley to the next activity

Tags: javascript, android, json, android-volley

My question is really simple.I am downloading the following and parsing the data in a listview.On item click from the listview i open a details page with further details of the item.I am unable to send this json data to the details activity.How do i handle this on this activity and in the details activity too?

My actvity code:

```js
public class Frontpage extends ActionBarActivity{
 private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private ListView lstView;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> arrNews ;
    private LayoutInflater lf;
    private VolleyAdapter va;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trending);
        
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

     Intent newActivity4=new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity4);
        
        
        lf = LayoutInflater.from(this);


        arrNews = new ArrayList<NewsModel>();
        va = new VolleyAdapter();

        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lstView.setAdapter(va);
        mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://pipes.yahooapis.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=giWz8Vc33BG6rQEQo_NLYQ&_render=json";
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading...","Please Wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(true); 
        try{
           
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

            }
        JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest
          (Request.Method.GET,url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
                parseJSON(response);
                va.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pd.dismiss();
;            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bummer..There's No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }};
            });
        mRequestQueue.add(jr);

 }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dismissPd();
    }

    private void dismissPd() {
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss();
            pd = null;
        }
    }

    private void parseJSON(JSONObject json){
        try{
            JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject("value");
            JSONArray items = value.getJSONArray("items");
            for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){

                    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    NewsModel nm = new NewsModel();
                    nm.setTitle(item.optString("title"));
                    nm.setDescription(item.optString("description"));
                    nm.setLink(item.optString("link"));
                    nm.setPubDate(item.optString("pubDate"));
                    arrNews.add(nm);
            }

            lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                     int position, long id) { 
              Intent intent = new Intent(Frontpage.this, NewsDetails.class);    
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
             });}


        
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Log cat:

12-29 22:33:07.701: E/Trace(1210): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-29 22:33:07.751: W/dalvikvm(1210): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
12-29 22:33:08.021: W/System.err(1210): Invalid int: ""
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): Local Branch: 
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): Local Patches: NONE
12-29 22:33:09.541: I/Adreno200-EGL(1210): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING
12-29 22:33:10.181: I/Choreographer(1210): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-29 22:33:19.971: I/Choreographer(1210): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-29 22:33:41.561: I/Frontpage(1210): {"value":{"callback":"","generator":"http://pipes.yahooapis.com/pipes/","pubDate":"Mon, 29 Dec 2014 19:33:38 +0000","title":"Cycling News","items":[{"guid":{"content":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,5d2ebd25-84e5-3b2c-9939-fa928362f76e-l:1","isPermaLink":"false"},"pubDate":"Thu, 25 Dec 2014 05:06:03 PST","category":"SC","title":"Trott announces engagement to British team mate Kenny (Reuters)","y:title":"Trott announces engagement to British team mate Kenny (Reuters)","y:id":{"value":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,5d2ebd25-84e5-3b2c-9939-fa928362f76e-l:1","permalink":"false"},"description":"LONDON (Reuters) - British Olympic track cycling gold medalists Laura Trott and Jason Kenny are to tie the knot. \"Merry Christmas everyone. I've had the most amazing couple of days thanks to @JasonKenny107 and the whole family #engaged\", Trott write on Twitter on Thursday. Trott, 22, took two golds at London 2012 in the team pursuit and omnium while 26-year-old Kenny also topped the podium in team sprint and individual sprint. Both are expected to be part of the British team for the Rio Olympics in 2016. (Editing by Martyn Herman)","link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/sc/SIG=137v5fe67/

http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/news/trott-announces-engagement-british-team-mate-kenny-130603685--spt.html","y:published":{"minute":"6","day_of_week":"4","utime":"1419512763","timezone":"UTC","day_name":"Thursday","second":"3","day_ordinal_suffix":"th","month":"12","year":"2014","month_name":"December","day":"25","hour":"13"},"y:repeatcount":"1"},{"guid":{"content":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,d8de91ac-8da9-3d9d-81bb-79a44e8d3c41-l:1","isPermaLink":"false"},"pubDate":"Fri, 19 Dec 2014 16:26:26 PST","media:content":{"type":"image/jpeg","url":"http://l.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/kuPd5jCbslBsMo8k0akURQ--/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTIwMDA7Y3I9MTtjdz0yMDAwO2R4PTUwMTtkeT0xO2ZpPXVsY3JvcDtoPTEzMDtxPTEwMDt3PTEzMA--/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/Sports/ap/201412191711618863458","width":"130","height":"130"},"category":"SC","title":"2 Armstrong associates settle lawsuit with Landis (The Associated Press)","y:title":"2 Armstrong associates settle lawsuit with Landis (The Associated Press)","y:id":{"value":"urn:newsml:sports.yahoo,lego:19780928:top,article,d8de91ac-8da9-3d9d-81bb-79a44e8d3c41-l:1","permalink":"false"},"description":"

</a></p>

AUSTIN, Texas (AP) -- Two of Lance Armstrong's longtime business partners have agreed to pay the federal government $500,000 to settle a whistleblower lawsuit filed by former teammate Floyd Landis.</p>","media:credit":{"content":"The Associated Press","role":"provider"},"link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/sports/rss/sc/SIG=13141nrib/

http%3A//sports.yahoo.com/news/2-armstrong-associates-settle-lawsuit-landis-223026201--spt.html","media:text":{"content":"FILE - In this Feb. 15, 2011 file photo, Lance Armstrong pauses during an interview in Austin, Texas. Two of Lance Armstrong's longtime business partners have agreed to pay the federal government $500,000 to settle a whistleblower lawsuit filed by a former teammate, Floyd Landis, Friday, Dec. 19, 
12-29 22:33:42.721: I/Choreographer(1210): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-29 22:33:54.031: W/dalvikvm(1210): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4159c438)
12-29 22:33:57.481: E/Trace(2300): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-29 22:33:57.531: W/dalvikvm(2300): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
12-29 22:33:57.651: W/System.err(2300): Invalid int: ""
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): Local Branch: 
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): Local Patches: NONE
12-29 22:33:58.181: I/Adreno200-EGL(2300): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING

Answer (score 0):

You can send simple data from one activity to another using the Intent. You can pass the JSON data as String using something like this:

```
intent.putExtra("OBJECT_DETAILS", myJSONString);
```

And later you can read in the next activity like this:

```
String myJsonData= i.getStringExtra("OBJECT_DETAILS");
```

Comment: For example in my code above when i want to send the title: `intent.putExtra("title", myJSONString);` Is this correct?

Comment: Well, the first parameter, is actually have to be a unique name to know how to read that value later, and the second parameter is the actual value. So you can do it how you write it, just be sure to later read it like this: String myJsonData= i.getStringExtra("title"); That doesn't mean that it's going to extract the "title" from inside the JSON string. In the other Activity you are going to receive any value contained in the myJSONString String.

Comment: i get you.But i am confused a bit.I have the title,description,link and pub date.Does the method above bind all these or do i have to pass individual for each item?

Comment: Do you have all those together in a single string? Or do you have them each one separated?

Comment: You are getting the json from the Web service, then you do parse it in order to show some data in the list. So now in the onClick, you have the position clicked, right? Now you can for example, convert the object in that position to JSON string again, pass to the next activity and convert it back to the NewsModel in the next activity. That way you can pass all the data at once, or you can send multiple strings, as much as you want, you can also send integers, Booleans, floats, etc.

Comment: yes yes thats exactly it.When you said i convert the object to string and pass it to the next activity you mean something like this:`String item=toString();
      Intent intent = new Intent(Frontpage.this, Detail.class);    
      intent.putExtra("json",item.toString());
         startActivity(intent);` Is this correct?

Comment: i am getting an exception and the details activty is stopping.From the activity code above please show me how to achieve this.I'm really a newbie and am really trying

Comment: Can you please share your logcat ? Would be good to identify why is the exception happening.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the exception part, when you app crashes, it should create a log with red letters, that's the important part in order to know what kind of exception is happening. You can also try to debug your app, put some breakpoint, trace it, see where is the crash happening.